# Compute settlement date for each trade entry in dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to compute the settlement date for each trade entry in dataframe, trade_list by looking up Country_code in dataframe, cash_mgmt_static to get trade_settlement_cycle.

`settlement date` can then be computed as `trade date + trade_settlement_cycle`.

How could I get `trade_settlement_cycle` in dataframe, `cash_mgmt_static` with `Country_code` as the lookup value in both dataframes?

Dataframe, `trade_list` is read from `trade_list.csv` which contains a list of trade entries.

Dataframe, `cash_mgmt_static` is read from `cash_mgmt_static` which contains static data of various markets.

```
trade_list <- read.csv("trade_list.csv", header=TRUE)
print(trade_list)
     Sedol                   Description Trans_type Trade_date  Quantity Price_local CCY_local Trade_value_local Trade_type Country_code
1  B01NPJ1 TATA CONSULTANCY SERVICES LTD        BUY  11-Jan-18    38,164       40.88       INR         1,560,044    Buy New           IN
2  B012W42                 PUBLIC BK BHD        BUY  11-Jan-18   221,400        4.92       MYR         1,089,969   Buy More           MY
3  6288190            AU OPTRONICS CORP.        BUY  11-Jan-18 2,210,000        0.42       TWD           923,639    Buy New           TW
4  6491318            KINGBOARD CHEMICAL        BUY  11-Jan-18   138,500        5.54       HKD           767,200    Buy New           HK
5  6205122                   INFOSYS LTD        BUY  11-Jan-18    48,855       15.30       INR           747,548    Buy New           IN

cash_mgmt_data <- read.csv("cash_mgmt_static.csv", header=TRUE)
print(cash_mgmt_data)
     Country_name Country_code CCY Trade_settlement_cycle BUY_funding_cycle Sell_repatriation_cycle FX_SI
1       Australia           AU AUD                      2                 2                       2    No
2          Canada           CA CAD                      2                 2                       2    No
3      Euro Union           EU EUR                      2                 2                       2    No
4       Hong Kong           HK HKD                      2                 2                       2    No
5           India           IN INR                      2                 1                       3    No
6           Korea           KR KRW                      2                 2                       2    No
7           Japan           JP JPY                      3                 3                       3    No
8        Malaysia           MY MYR                      3                 3                       3    No
9     New Zealand           NZ NZD                      2                 2                       2    No
10     Philipines           PH PHP                      3                 3                       3    No
11      Singapore           SG SGD                      3                 3                       3    No
12    Switzerland           CH CHF                      2                 2                       2    No
13         Taiwan           TW TWD                      2                 1                       2    No
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Are you just looking for `merge(trade_list, cash_mgmt_data)`? Can you show the desired output for your sample input?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you helping. I tried with match and it works.

```
library("readxl")
cash_mgmt_static <- read.csv("cash_mgmt_static.csv", header=TRUE)
trade_list <- read.csv("trade_list.csv", header=TRUE)

country_code <- trade_list[row, "Country_code"]
trade_settlement_cycle <- cash_mgmt_data[match(trade_list$Country_code,cash_mgmt_data$Country_code),"Trade_settlement_cycle"]
trade_list$Trade_date = as.Date(trade_list$Trade_date, format= "%d-%B-%y")
trade_list$Settle_date <- trade_list$Trade_date + trade_settlement_cycle
print(trade_list)
```